# Why does method tracing improve the performance of my application?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I'm developing an application whos performance was bad, so I tried method tracing. I figrured out that the performance of the application was improved significantly by adding the folling two statements in direct succession.

```
android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing("MyTracing");
android.os.Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

I think I understand what method tracing is for but I don't understand why the performance significantly improves when I add these lines.

I oberserve the same improvement by hitting the start/stop method tracing button in CPU-View of the android monitor. There I recognise a decreasing workload of the Kernel CPU after stopping the method tracing.

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? Is there another way to improve the performance without using method tracing?